# set image dynamically to the custom imageview class android

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I want to load the url into ImageView and that url is dynamic, so I created the custom Imageview class like this

```
public class CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor extends AppCompatImageView {
public CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Glide.with(context).load(SessionManager.getCountryWiseDataObject(context).getCurrencyImageWhite()).into(this);
}

public CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Glide.with(context).load(SessionManager.getCountryWiseDataObject(context).getCurrencyImageWhite()).into(this);
}

public CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    Glide.with(context).load(SessionManager.getCountryWiseDataObject(context).getCurrencyImageWhite()).into(this);
}
```

}

.Its working fine when I used it the following way

```
 <com.kiran.example.ebitcoin.customview.CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/imageSizeTooSmallBTCLogo"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/imageSizeTooSmallBTCLogo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Now, I want to change the image resource of this custom image too, dynamically, So I tried

```
 CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor img = findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bitcoin_24_white);
```

But unfortunately, nothing is changed. How to change the image of custom image view class dynamically?? Any one found answer of this?

Comment: try `this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bitcoin_24_white)` if you are in a fragment then `getContext().`

Comment: thanx for ur reply, but no change in output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally , I got answer of my own question. I follow [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/588), and done the code by following way.

```
public class CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor extends AppCompatImageView {
Context context;
public CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Glide.with(context).load(SessionManager.getCountryWiseDataObject(context).getCurrencyImageWhite()).into(this);
}

public CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Glide.with(context).load(SessionManager.getCountryWiseDataObject(context).getCurrencyImageWhite()).into(this);
}

public CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    Glide.with(context).load(SessionManager.getCountryWiseDataObject(context).getCurrencyImageWhite()).into(this);
}

public void setImageWithGlide(Context context, Integer resId) {
    this.context = context;
    Glide.with(context).load("").placeholder(resId).into(this);
}
```

}

To change the image dynamically,

```
CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor img = findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageWithGlide(this, R.drawable.image);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are extending `AppCompatImageView` you can do as following:

```
Drawable drawable = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_bitcoin_24_white); 
img.setImageResource(drawable);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but getting `AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)`

Comment: It's a bug in the library. Add `@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")` to your method which contains the above lines.

Comment: What version of appCompat are you using ? Can you add your code scope to your question?

Comment: I am using compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

Well u already use Glide in the first place, so try do it this way:

create setImageWithGlide method in CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor

```
public void setImageWithGlide(Context context, String imagePath) {
   Glide.with(context).load(imagePath).into(this)
}

public void setImageWithGlide(Context context, Integer resId) {
   Glide.with(context).load(resId).into(this)
}
```

you can use it like this:

```
img.setImageWithGlide(imagePath);
```

or if u use resourceId

```
img.setImageWithGlide(R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: thanx for your reply, I tried ` public void setImageMethod( Integer resId) {
        this.setImageResource(resId);
    }`

and 
` CustomLocalCurrencyImageViewWhiteColor img = findViewById(R.id.img);
img.setImageMethod(R.drawable.ic_bitcoin_24_white);`

But still no change

Comment: why do you need to use this.setImageResource instead of using Glide.with() ?

Comment: thanks for clarifying , I have made the suggested changes, now image is not getting visible